# Check whether the propositional formula is a tautology and satisfiable

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If A happens, B or C will happen. If B will not happen, D will happen. If D and A happen, C will not happen. Therefore, B will happen.

I wrote this propositional formula:

$(A \Rightarrow (B \lor C)) \land (\neg B \Rightarrow D) \land ((D \land A) \Rightarrow \neg C) \Rightarrow B$

How to check is it a tautology and is it satisfiable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to show that it is possible for it to be false for some truth values of the statement letters $A,B,C,D$

First for the implication ot be false, one must have
$$
\underbrace{(A \Rightarrow (B \lor C)) \land (\neg B \Rightarrow D) \land ((D \land A) \Rightarrow \neg C)}_{true} \Rightarrow \underbrace{B}_{false} \\
$$
for the antecedent to be true all conjuncts must be so, with the assumption that $B$ is *false*. That means that $D$ must be *true*. Also for the other two conjunts to be true, since they are implications, it is sufficient to have $A$ to be *false*. $C$ can be *true* or *false*.

$$
B=f\\
C=t\\
A=f\\
D=t/f
$$
So it is not a tautology. Furthermore if $A=D=C=t$ then the statement form is true.

Comment: thanks. and is it satisfiable? should i check a negation of it not to be a tautology?

Comment: what do you mean with satisfiable, please ?

Comment: If you make $A=D=C=t$ then it will be true

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability